# Using Seaborn split violin plots and palettes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm creating a set of grouped violin plots with the following:

```
fig = plt.figure(1)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
sns.violinplot(x='x', y='y1', data=df_y1_all, split=True, inner=None, hue="hues_param", palette={"left":"r","right":"b"})
ax1.legend()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
sns.violinplot(x='x', y='y2', data=df_y2_all, split=True, inner=None, hue="hues_param", palette={"left":"r","right":"b"})

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)
sns.violinplot(x='x', y='y3', data=df_y3_all, split=True, inner=None, hue="hues_param", palette={"left":"r","right":"b"})
ax3.legend('')

plt.show()
```

Which creates something like the following (I've omitted some of the sensitive parameter names as this is pre-published work):

[image: plot]

I'd like to have a gradient of reds and a gradient of blues as per the argument `palette={"left":"r","right":"b"}`, but when I try to pass names of color palettes I get an error:

`ValueError: Could not generate a palette for ['Blues', 'Reds']` or for any other 'named' Seaborn palette.

As my data is sensitive I can't share the original dataframe, but it's based on the working example from the [docs](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_violinplots.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)

# Load the example tips dataset
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# Draw a nested violinplot and split the violins for easier comparison
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, split=True,
               inner="quart", palette={"Male": "b", "Female": "y"})
sns.despine(left=True)
```

Which produces:

[image: plot2]

Is there anyway to control the palette gradient or call a pre-made gradient within the plot arguments?

Thanks!

Comment: Not within seaborn. Using matplotlib you have the option to create a gradient image and clip it by some path, which could in this case be the half-violin in question.